# Shell script to log into a particular site

Tags: bash, shell, browser, login-script, lynx

I need to login to the Internet Access Portal of our college to get access to the Internet. (Cyberoam) I need to keep this window opened all the time. The address is `http://192.168.0.1:8090/httpclient.html` I need to enter the username and password there to login.

I'm new to scripting. I need help make a script which:
1. Opens Lynx
2. Goes to: `http://192.168.0.1:8090/httpclient.html`
3. Automatically enters my username and password
4. Keeps me logged in

I need to do this because it is a pain to log in manually each time. If my browser needs updating, it won't update as I don't have internet access yet.

Answer (score 1):

Use curl to post your username and password.

`curl --data "login=userid&pass=password" http://192.168.0.1:8090/httpclient.html`.

**EDIT:**

I am assuming your college is using Cyberoam. In this case you need to keep open a window with login portal. 
then for using lynx

```
echo "login=userid&pass=password\n--\n" | lynx -post_data http://192.168.0.1:8090/httpclient.html
```

should work.

**EDIT:**

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12387165/3341358) may be useful for your case as well.

**EDIT:**

Comeup with an another answer that may help you, since other didn't worked for you. I used curl with lynx for this one.

```
curl -d "login=userid&pass=password" http://192.168.0.1:8090/httpclient.html | lynx -stdin
```

Even after this if you see a login window then refresh the page and there will be no login window. I have tried this for many sites and this worked for all.

Comment: Thanks Dheerendra. I made a shell script as suggested, I'll post the contents below. '#!/bin/bash
echo "login=student&pass=student" | lynx -post_data http://192.168.0.1:8090/httpclient.html
' But, it did not work. Am I doing anything wrong? When I run the script using the 'bash login.sh' command, it does nothing, just waits as if it is doing something.

Comment: did you checked if the login and pass variable names are same?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. The login and password are correct.

Comment: sorry, my mistake. input must be terminated by --. so use `echo "login=userid&pass=password\n--\n" | lynx -post_data http://192.168.0.1:8090/httpclient.html`

Comment: It still didn't work bhaiyya. :) The script runs but nothing happens.

Comment: updated my answer. Check it now. And btw bhaiyya??? didn't saw that coming from a 21 year old person.

Comment: I didn't check out your profile. Thanks bro. Still didn't work. A screenshot of what happens [link](http://i.imgur.com/9Qas44q.png)

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Will you please confirm the form inputs from the page source of your login form?

Comment: @Babbzzz since you don't know the form logic details, i figured out my myself. You should use `curl -d "username=userid&password=password&btnSubmit=Login" http://192.168.0.1:8090/httpclient.html | lynx -stdin`

Comment: Sorry about the late response. Not been in college for a week. I'll tell you on Saturday. Thanks.