# Shell: how to pass georgian (utf-8) character key to a specific field on a website with lynx

Tags: shell, http, parsing, unicode, lynx

```
lynx -accept_all_cookies $URL -cmd_script=bar.txt

bar.txt:

key <tab> //get to first field
key <tab> //get to second field
key ძ     //utf=8 input ძ
key ე     //utf=8 input ე
key ბ     //utf=8 input ბ
key ნ     //utf=8 input ნ
key ა     //utf=8 input ა
key <tab> //get to third field
key <tab> //get to fourth field
key <tab> //get to sumbit button
key ^J    //click submit and wait for load
key <tab> //get to hyperlink
key ^J    //click hyperlink and wait for load
key Q     //exit
key y     //confirm exit
```

The above attempt, adapted from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385795/shell-connecting-to-a-website-and-accessing-a-field/12387165#12387165), works fine for Ascii characters but not for Georgian input characters.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The characters you want to send are multibyte UTF-8 sequences, and the lynx command script `key` command only sends a single 8-bit byte. So you have to break the characters into individual bytes and send each byte separately.

That's a little annoying; the simplest way to do it might be to use the `-cmd_log` option to create a log file while you type the characters you want to send.

However, you can do this with bash:

```
$ georgian=ძებნა
$ (export LC_ALL=C; printf "key 0x%2x\n" $(sed 's/./"& /g' <<<"$georgian"); )
key 0xe1
key 0x83
key 0xab
key 0xe1
key 0x83
key 0x94
key 0xe1
key 0x83
key 0x91
key 0xe1
key 0x83
key 0x9c
key 0xe1
key 0x83
key 0x90
```

That bash command is probably a little obscure :-). Here's a quick breakdown:

```sh
(                         # Start a subshell to isolate environment change
 export LC_ALL=C;         # In the subshell, set the locale to plain ascii
 printf "key 0x%2x\n"     # Apply this format to each argument
        $(                # Substitute the result of running the following
          sed             # Editor command
              's/./"& /g' # Change each byte to <"><byte><space>
              <<<"$georgian"  # Fabricate an input stream for sed
                              # using the value of shell variable $georgian
        );                # End of command substitution
)                         # End of subshell
```

Unlike C `printf` (and others), the shell `printf` repeats its pattern until all arguments have been handled. And, as another idiosyncracy, if the format is numeric (such as `%x`, which formats its argument in hexadecimal and the corresponding argument starts with a `"`, the number used for the argument is the character code of the second character in the argument (i.e. the one after the `"`).

The `sed` command turns a byte-sequence into a series of arguments with exactly this form; it's important to not quote the command substitution so that the individual substitutions will be treated as separate arguments. That means that the command won't work if `$georgian` contains any shell metacharacter, but since all shell metacharacters are simple ascii characters, there won't be any problem provided that every character in `$georgian` is, in fact, Georgian. (But don't put spaces in the string. They'll get silently dropped.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. It's clear now where was the problem. And thank you very much for your solution too. It works fine now!

Here is my alternative for breaking a multi-byte character into individual bytes: 
$ echo -n "$georgian" | od -w1 -An -t xC | sed 's|^ |key 0x|'

Answer (score 0):

Here is my alternative for breaking a multi-byte character into individual bytes:

```
$ georgian=ძებნა    
$ echo -n "$georgian" | od -w1 -An -t xC | sed 's|^ |key 0x|'
key 0xe1
key 0x83
key 0xab
key 0xe1
key 0x83
key 0x94
key 0xe1
key 0x83
key 0x91
key 0xe1
key 0x83
key 0x9c
key 0xe1
key 0x83
key 0x90
```