# open email address by linux command

Tags: linux

I want to make a script shell which allow to enter my email and my password and if the email address is correct the browser will be opened at home page of the web application.

example:

> the URL of my application is : `http://ipaddress/webAppli` to enter to
>   this application I have to login with the email @ and passwords.  so I
>   want to know if there is a script shell to do this action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try here:
[bash script to login to webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12255124/bash-script-to-login-to-webpage/12264038#12264038)

I have given a bit of java code to do exactly this

sorry thats to login to a web page you want a mechanism to authenticate to the page via a shell script ?

It sounds quite confusing .. where is the email address and password authenticated against a mail server ? a web mail ? or does the web page itself require authentication?

Comment: 1) yes I want a mechanism to authenticate to the page via a shell script  
 
2) use email address not to login to mailbox but to authenticate to web application

Comment: right well that all depends on how the web page works - for example can you do a get ? look at the link provided, I provided 2 examples 1 using curl which uses a url formatted as a GET request with ?username=something&password=something as the example. If how ever you need to post your details then using that Java code would be a good way forward. I presume once their logged in to the web page you wish to browse the page logged in ? which in both cases it establishes a cookie then proceeds to link provided once normally logged in

Comment: If it is a public facing web mail system either open source or if you can provide the web link since in order to do this sort of thing you will need to inspect the web mail system to see how it operates where it posts to what fields it uses where does it end up once it is logged in. etc you can install firefox plugins to try help you or view the source and if you understand html to figure out its actions then you can configure the bit of Java code to do the exact actions and pretend it is a user logged in, parse the  output calling the class within  script, action its output accordingly